# Node.js: handle JSON object in client side

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am having trouble handling a `JSON` object at the client side of a `Node.js` server using `socket.io`.

This is how I'm sending the data (the file I'm reading has JSON format):

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("A user connected");
    fs.readFile('/.../file.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        socket.emit('news', JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("A user disconnected");
    });
});
```

I call `JSON.stringify` in order to give a readable format to the binary `data`.

Now, in the client side, I have the following `<script>` block inside the html's `<body>`:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('news', function(data){
        var obj= JSON.parse(data);
        $("#json").text(obj);
    });
</script>
```

This runs fine, I have a paragraph `<p id="json"></p>` which takes the whole block of text, but if I try to access an element of the parsed JSON and print it, e.g. the "timestamp" tag using `console.log(obj.timestamp)` I get `undefined`.

How can I handle the data I'm receiving so I can handle it as a regular JSON?

**EDIT**

This is the output of `console.log(obj)`:

```
{
"timestamp": "Wed Aug 27 13:14:01 CEST 2014",
"devices": [
    {
        "A": {
            "mac": "00:07:80:68:18:41",
            "handles": [
                {
                    "TxHandler1": "0418",
                    "TxHandler2": "020f00072a",
                    "TxHandler3": "bd",
                    "a": {
                        "hnd": "0x0010",
                        "uuid": "00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "0a 18 "
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "hnd": "0x0011",
                        "uuid": "00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "02 12 00 29 2a "
                    },
                    "c": {
                        "hnd": "0x0012",
                        "uuid": "00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "56 4c "
                    },
                    "d": {
                        "hnd": "0x0013",
                        "uuid": "00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "46 41 "
                    },
                    "e": {
                        "hnd": "0x0014",
                        "uuid": "00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "02 15 00 24 2a "
                    },
                    "f": {
                        "hnd": "0x0015",
                        "uuid": "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "31 31 "
                    },
                    "g": {
                        "hnd": "0x0016",
                        "uuid": "00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "4d 4f 44 "
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "B": {
            "mac": "00:07:80:68:18:8E",
            "handles": [
                {
                    "TxHandler1": "0418",
                    "TxHandler2": "020f00072a",
                    "TxHandler3": "bd",
                    "a": {
                        "hnd": "0x0010",
                        "uuid": "00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "0a 18 "
                    },
                    "b": {
                        "hnd": "0x0011",
                        "uuid": "00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "02 12 00 29 2a "
                    },
                    "c": {
                        "hnd": "0x0012",
                        "uuid": "00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "56 4c "
                    },
                    "d": {
                        "hnd": "0x0013",
                        "uuid": "00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "46 41 "
                    },
                    "e": {
                        "hnd": "0x0014",
                        "uuid": "00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "02 15 00 24 2a "
                    },
                    "f": {
                        "hnd": "0x0015",
                        "uuid": "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "31 31 "
                    },
                    "g": {
                        "hnd": "0x0016",
                        "uuid": "00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb",
                        "value": "4d 4f 44 "
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

which, according to JSON Lint, is a valid json, but still I'm getting `undefined` when I try to access the "timestamp" tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending the wrong data format, the correct code is:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("A user connected");
    fs.readFile('/.../file.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        socket.emit('news', data.toString());
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log("A user disconnected");
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should accept your own answer if it worked ;)

Comment: I tried but it says I need to come back in 2 days and accept it. I'll do it then ;)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no relation between the client and the server. The fact that you use node.js that happens to be JavaScript should have nothing to do with the client.

If you had the same action done in C# or Java, would it matter to the client?

Bottom line, step 1 should be verifying that you JSON object is received correctly on the client. Then, make sure you JSON is a valid object using a validator such as [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/). If it's invalid, then the problem is on the server side. If not, you need to check your client side's parsing.

Comment: I'm calling `JSON.parse` in both sides to check is the data I'm handling is correct and I'm not getting any errors. I also copy-pasted the output of `console.log(obj)` in JSON Lint and it says it's a valid json